# RTK Query Testing Error with MSW and vitest

Tags: reactjs, vite, rtk-query, vitest, msw

I'm trying to test a component in React that uses RTK Query + MSW + Vitest. It works fine on the browser but while testing RTK Query with vitest it throws this error:

`{ status: 'FETCH_ERROR', error: 'TypeError: fetch failed' }`

I've setup a [public repo](https://github.com/albertofcasuso/rtk-query-msw-vitest-error) with the configuration i'm using to replicate the error.

Another error RTK Query throws only while testing is:

`TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/test?page=1&limit=10`

This happens when i setup the fetchBaseQuery - baseUrl as empty or as a relative URL. I have to specify 'http://localhost...' or it wont work. But, it works in the browser.

[Repo with the error](https://github.com/albertofcasuso/rtk-query-msw-vitest-error)

Followed some articles on the matter with no success
Searched Stackoverflow and found
Searched RTK query repo issues and found a similar issue but with jest instead of vitest
I've tried clearing query cache between tests - no success.

App.jsx

```
import { useTestQuery } from "./services/test";

export const App = () => {
  const { data } = useTestQuery({ page: 1, limit: 10 });
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data ? data.data.map((i) => i) : "loading"}</h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

redux/index.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { testApi } from "../services/test";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [testApi.reducerPath]: testApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat([testApi.middleware]),
});
setupListeners(store.dispatch);

export default store;
```

services/apiSetup.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const emptyApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl:"http://localhost:3000"
  }),
  tagTypes: ["test"],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

services/test.js

```
import { emptyApi } from "./apiSetup";

export const testApi = emptyApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    test: build.query({
      query: ({ page = 1, limit = 10 }) => {
        return { url: `test?page=${page}&limit=${limit}` };
      },
      providesTags: ["test"],
      transformErrorResponse: (result) => console.log(result),
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});

export const { useTestQuery,usePrefetch } =
  testApi;
```

mocks/server.js

```
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { handlers } from './handlers';

export const server = setupServer(...handlers);
```

mocks/handler.js

```
import { test } from "./handlers/test";

export const handlers = [...test];
```

mocks/handlers/test.js

```
import { rest } from "msw";

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

export const test = [
  rest.get("http://localhost:3000/test", (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log(req)
    return res(
      ctx.delay(randomIntFromInterval(100, 1000)),
      ctx.status(200),
      ctx.json({ data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], total: 5 })
    );
  }),
];
```

testSetup.js

```
import { expect, afterEach, vi } from "vitest";
import { server } from "../mocks/server";
import { cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import matchers from "@testing-library/jest-dom";

// extends Vitest's expect method with methods from react-testing-library
expect.extend(matchers);


beforeAll(() => server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: "bypass", cors: true }));

afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers();
  cleanup();
});

afterAll(() => server.close());
```

App.test.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { describe, expect, test } from "vitest";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../../redux";
import App from "./";

const wrapper = (children) => {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};

function setup(jsx) {
  return {
    ...render(wrapper(jsx)),
  };
}

describe("App test", () => {
  test("Should test", async () => {
    setup(<App />);
    await screen.findByText(/12345/);
    screen.debug(undefined, 50000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here.

Comment: Just as an update,  I've tried moving from Vitest to Jest and the exact same configuration works correctly in Jest.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: Hello, have you resolved this issue? I am also facing the same issue with msw. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `msw 1.1.0`, after release https://github.com/mswjs/msw/pull/1545 everything seems to work fine with your setup.

Comment: Already using 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you get `FETCH_ERROR` in your tests with RTK Query, MSW, vitest, then most likely you'll need to define `fetch` in a setup function, similar to: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/67a69e876812282ad7fe5590d173a88bd7b80282/packages/toolkit/jest.setup.js

```
//@ts-ignore
const nodeFetch = require('node-fetch')
//@ts-ignore
global.fetch = nodeFetch
//@ts-ignore
global.Request = nodeFetch.Request
```

Comment: Now it says Request is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you're here like me and

1. Providing global fetch doesn't work
2. Updating MSW doesn't work
3. You're defining full baseURL and mocking that correctly

But it still doesn't work, check if you have tried fixing jest polyfills before as part of the MSW migration guide.

https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x/#frequent-issues

They suggest polyfilling Request/Response which messes with your fetch in RTK, which was needed in my case but I added it because instructions said so.

Just remove this section and see if still works:

```
const { Blob, File } = require('node:buffer')
const { fetch, Headers, FormData, Request, Response } = require('undici')
 
Object.defineProperties(globalThis, {
  fetch: { value: fetch, writable: true },
  Blob: { value: Blob },
  File: { value: File },
  Headers: { value: Headers },
  FormData: { value: FormData },
  Request: { value: Request }, 
  Response: { value: Response }, <-- This one caused issues with RTK for me
})
```

Hope it helps.